# How to write string params for JSON in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How would I write strong params for this JSON, if I have Map model where i want to save these records:

```
{
"map":[
  {"lat": "51.088672", "lon": "71.396522", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:00"},
  {"lat": "51.088672", "lon": "71.396453", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:01"},
  {"lat": "51.088829", "lon": "71.396476", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:14"} 
 ]
}
```

I have already tried something like that:

```
params.require(:map).permit(:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent)

params.permit(map: [:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent])

params.permit(map: [:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent]).require(:maps)
```

Comment: Your `JSON params` looks wrong. Are you sure those are correct?

Comment: @Pavan, i checked at JSONlint.com

Comment: Try `params.permit({map: [:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent]})`

Comment: The json data is coming via post request?

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope this will help.

```
before_action :parse_json_data_to_params, except: [ # Put Your Get Actions Names Here otherwise it will raise error for get requests ]

def parse_json_data_to_params
  params.merge!(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post))
end
```

and in params permit method.

```
params.require(:map).permit(:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent)
```

Comment: please add `puts "#{params.inspect}" ` before permit statement in permit params method and post the params value.